# Ok to double plywood under flooring?

Tags: subfloor

My house is on pilings, with plywood subflooring nailed to engineered truss joists, and carpet or hardwood on top of that.

I've pulled up the carpet in preparation for installing vinyl plank floors.

I'm now considering putting an additional layer of plywood to help with noise below and to add rigidity and improve flatness that uneven joists have made difficult.

Is it problematic to add a second layer of plywood? Are there gotchas that I should know if I go this route?

Comment: Will add to rigidity, but since it will be screwed down won't help much to improve flatness.  Has to be tight to subfloor, so need to improve flatness first.

Comment: engineered joists should not be uneven.  something unusual is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Leveling things would be first.
I am a big guy so I like a thick floor it is fine to add but remember you will need to trim molding at doors.

When you lay the new layer make sure to offset the seams, this will make a much better floor. Offsetting is making sure the seams are not on top of each other. If full sheets are used it can be as simple as cutting the first sheet in half.

Comment: Should I attach the second layer in any way?

Comment: I like screws. With my own property in the past I have used construction adhesive it cost more but that and screws make a really good rigid base.

Comment: Thanks. Just making sure that it shouldn't float.